# ASP.NET MVC lost in finding botleneck

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, debugging, profiling

I have `ASP.NET MVC` app which accept file uploads and has result pooling using SignalR. The app hosted on Prod server with IIS7, 4 Gb Ram and two cores CPU.

The app on Dev server works perfectly but when I host it on Prod server with about `50 000 users per day` the app become unrresponsible after five minutes of running. The web page request time increase dramatically and it takes about 30 seconds to load one page. I have tried to record all `MvcApplication.Application_BeginRequest` event call and got `9000` hits in `5 minutes`. Not sure is this acceptable number of hits or not for app like this.

I have used ANTS Performance Profiler(not useful in Prod app profiling, slow and eats all memory) to profile code but profiler do not show any time delay issues in my code/MSSQL queries.

Also I have tried to monitored CPU and RAM spike problems but I didn't find any. CPU percentage sometimes goes to 15% but never up and memory usage is normal.

I suspect that there is something wrong with request or threads limits in ASP.NET/IIS7 but don't know how to profile it.

Could someone suggest any profiling solutions which could help in this situation? Tried to hunt the problem for two week already without any result :(

Comment: It sounds like you are burning through some resources and are having to wait for them to free up. I would check my code to make sure all DB connections are closed after use, all service clients are disposed and any memory hungry objects are disposed as soon as they are done.

Answer (score 2):

You may try using the [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) and more specifically the [`MiniProfiler.MVC3`](http://nuget.org/packages/miniprofiler.mvc3) NuGet package which is specifically created for ASP.NET MVC applications. It will show you all kind of useful information such as the time spend for different methods in the execution of the request.